# Summing values in repeated sections in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I have a problem when it comes to suming values from a repeated section. Specifically, when I have a repeated section in the orbeon builder with a control that has a value I can easily sum the values of these sections in a different control using sum($control-1) - in the calculated value. When inputing values in the form preview the sum is correct in  my control with the summed value. 
Unfortunately, when I add a section using the +Insert Below button in the form preview while testing the form the sum() function doesn't work anymore. In the control with this calculated value nothing is shown. Is there a different way to get the sum of values from repeated sections or is this a bug in orbeon?

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a new section while testing the form the sum() function doesn't work anymore, because it adds a empty element to the node-set.
In XPath, when using the sum function, the value of each node is determined by trying to converting it to a number (number()), if there is a empty value, it's gonna convert to NaN, thus in the control with this calculated value nothing is shown by Orbeon.

A different way that would work would be to use the expression like: sum($control-1[text()]) . This way you are testing if the node has content before trying to sum it, so it's always gonna work.